# small space keeps showing to right side of my website w

Tags: html, css, width, overflow, viewport

I've been having this issue with this webpage I've been working on. Whenever I view the page in google chrome on my mac, I get a sliver of space to the right of page when I scroll to the right. I'm not really sure how to fix the problem. Here's an image to show what I'm talking about, along with my html and css. Thanks in advance to anyone that can help me.

Image:
http://imgur.com/0JAZsgg&KcUfJZl&ephxQZC#2

Here's my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../scripts/javascript/responsive_drop_down.js"></script>
    <link href="../css/main_stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
    <link href="../css/print_stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print"/>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <header>
            <h1>This is a placeholder <br />
                for header</h1>
        </header>

        <nav class="nm">
            <div class="mobilmenu"></div>
            <div class="mobile-container">
                <ul>
                    <li class="white"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="red"><a href="#">Video</a></li>
                    <li class="purple"><a href="#">Pictures</a></li>
                    <li class="blue"><a href="#">Audio</a></li>
                    <li class="green"><a href="#">Other Work</a></li>
                    <li class="yellow"><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
                    <li class="gray"><a href="#">Contact Me</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>    
        </nav>

        <div class="content-container">

            <article class="content-main">
                <section>
                    <h1>Heading goes here...</h1>
                    <time datetime="#">Time will go here.</time>
                    <p>Content will go here...</p>
                </section>
            </article>

            <aside class="sidebar">
                    <p>More Content to come soon.</p>
            </aside>
        </div>    

        <div class="footer-position">
            <footer>
                <span class="copyright">All rights reserved 2014.</span>

                <nav class="nf">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Video</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Pictures</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Audio</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Other Work</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact Me</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </nav>
              </footer>
           </div>    
       </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Here's the css:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:300,400,300italic,400italic);
@font-face 
{
font-family: 'bebas_neueregular';
src: url('../font/BebasNeue/bebasneue-webfont.eot');
src: url('../font/BebasNeue/bebasneue-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), 
     url('../font/BebasNeue/bebasneue-webfont.woff') format('woff'), 
     url('../font/BebasNeue/bebasneue-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), 
     url('../font/BebasNeue/bebasneue-webfont.svg#bebas_neueregular') format('svg'), 
     url('../font/BebasNeue/BebasNeu.otf') format('opentype');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;

}


body
{
width:100%;
font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
margin:0;
padding:0;
background-color:#84888B;
overflow-y:scroll;
direction:ltr;
display:block;
}

#wrapper
{
display:block;
width:100%;
margin:0 auto;
padding:0 auto;
}

header
{
font-family:'bebas_neueregular', sans-serif;
background-color:#5D0660;
color:#E21208;
text-align:center;
padding:15px;
}

nav
{
display:block;
font-family:'bebas_neueregular', sans-serif;
text-align:center;
overflow:hidden;
}

nav ul
{
list-style:none;
}

nav ul li
{
display:inline-block;
}

nav ul li a
{
text-decoration:none;
}

nav.nm
{
width:100%;
background-color:#000000;
font-size:125%;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

nav.nm ul
{
margin:0 auto;
margin-top:0;
}

nav.nm ul li a
{
display:block;
color:#ffffff;
padding:15px 16px;
}

nav.nm ul li a:hover
{
color:#000000;
-webkit-transition:450ms ease;
-moz-transition:450ms ease;
transition:450ms ease;
}

nav.nm ul li.white a:hover
{
background-color:#ffffff;
}

nav.nm ul li.red a:hover
{
background-color:#E21208;
}

nav.nm ul li.purple a:hover
{
background-color:#9E00A3;
}

nav.nm ul li.blue a:hover
{
background-color:#1A297F;
}

nav.nm ul li.green a:hover
{
background-color:#319032;
}

nav.nm ul li.yellow a:hover
{
background-color:#E1E13D;
}

nav.nm ul li.gray a:hover
{
background-color:#84888B;
}

nav.nf
{
font-size:85%;
}

nav.nf ul li:last-child 
{
border-right:none;
}

nav.nf ul li 
{
border-right:1px solid #000000;
}

nav.nf ul li a
{
display:block;
padding:2px 9px;
color:#000000;
}

nav.nf ul li a:hover
{
color:#ffffff;
}



footer
{
width:100%;
background-color:#1A297F;
text-align:center;
margin-top:38.6%;
padding:0.2%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried your code on my Windows 8 machine and I can't find any problems. Your screenshot looks like a margin problem. If you aren't familiar with how margins and padding work this little diagram over at html dog has helped me understand how it works:

http://www.htmldog.com/guides/css/beginner/margins/

If the problem is specific to Google chrome on the Mac (which I don't have access to unfortunately) I would think that the default CSS styling of that version of chrome could be getting in the way. A good CSS reset could fix the problem:

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Just copy and paste that code into your CSS file, any of your code that appropriately over rides the CSS reset will take precedence, leaving the reset to fix any little differences between browsers.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out. Actually, there was another website that I did a while ago, and the problem was more noticeable when viewing on google chrome for android. One other thing, I am familiar with how margin and padding works. I just haven't gotten a whole practice at using either since I just got finished with taking web design I.